# How does R interrupt handling work?

Tags: r

In R, when an interrupt signal (e.g. Ctrl+C) is sent, does the R code detect this change by periodically calling a function to check the signal (e.g. R_CheckUserInterrupt();) or does the operating system "stop" the running code and execute some process (which is how I understand the Boehm Garbage Collector works, suspending execution of running threads when a signal arrives).

I know in externally compiled functions the interrupts are disabled, but how does it work in typical R code?

Comment: Most of R is written in C, and interrupt handling is left to the authors of packages. Well written code will stop execution and return to the console. Not all code is "well writtten" by this criterion. You should look at `?stopifnot` , `?stop`, `?signalConditions` , and then look at their coded implementation.

Comment: So it's always depend on the code checking for the interrupt?

Comment: That's the impression I had from looking at things like: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/1f90637a59dcfd646205e716896223a9e2a0155c/src/main/eval.c#L543 but wasn't sure